# Substraction between two MySQL's time variable with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time

I show my problem:

I have two variables that contain the TIME variable from an MySQL database:

```
$row[0] //it contains for instance 16:30:00
$row[1] //it contains for instance 18:00:00
```

How do I find the term that is derived from their subtraction?

As they are already time variables I tried to do a subtraction directly with these values ​​but I get integer values ​​rounded down.

I tried existing questions but none foresaw a time in the format HH: MM: SS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
$query = select TIMEDIFF(field_name, '$input_date') from tbl_name where condition
```

at mysql

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you very much! As soon as possible I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `TIMEDIFF` function instead of substrction:

```
SELECT REPLACE(TIMEDIFF(col1,col2),'-','')
```

`REPLACE` is used to ensure absolute result.

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answerd... well
You need to convert it on timestamps

```
$time1 = strtotime($row[0]);
$time2 = strtotime($row[1]);
$diff = $time2 - $time1;
```

Also be aware if it use after 1 day, it will not show the "last day" difference... So use year month day...