# how to subtract time only(hours minutes second) no day or month

Tags: mysql

I need to subtract time values in  a column type time - only hours minutes , seconds are inserted no days or months- to a certain numbers to make different timezones

when I use for example

```
SELECT subtime('01:00:00', "9:30:00")
```

it returns

-08:30:00

on the other hand 
if I switch them to subtime( "9:30:00" , '01:00:00')
it returns

08:30:00 
 while the required value should be 3:30:00

how can I subtract time without getting minus ?

Comment: SUBTIME(a,b) works like a-b. So if a < b you will get negative value. just use `SELECT subtime("9:30:00",'01:00:00')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I subtract using SQL in MYSQL between two date time values and retrieve the result in minutes or second?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981262/how-do-i-subtract-using-sql-in-mysql-between-two-date-time-values-and-retrieve-t)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Substraction between two MySQL's time variable with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262952/substraction-between-two-mysqls-time-variable-with-php)

Comment: make sure that your time format is 24 hours, and then switch the positions of both times !

Comment: @Hytool unfortunately switching does not solve any problem , as "9:30:00" - '01:00:00' = 8:30:00 
while I need 9 hours before 1 o'clock which is 16 o'clock

Comment: @0X0nosugar datetime is different , my variable are only times and functions do not show  the right values for 24 hours or 12 hours

Comment: @MohsenShakibafar your link is php , mysql solution is preferred

Comment: if 16 o'clock is required then try this, SELECT  TIME(SUBDATE(CAST(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ','01:00:00') AS datetime) , INTERVAL '09:00' HOUR_MINUTE)) AS your_time;

Comment: @Yosra Nagati - Thanks for claryfying. In this case I think your question is no duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT IF(CAST('01:00:00' AS TIME) > CAST('9:30:00' AS TIME), SUBTIME('01:00:00', '9:30:00'), SUBTIME('9:30:00', '01:00:00'));
```

Comment: unfortunately switching does not solve any problem , as "9:30:00" - '01:00:00' = 8:30:00 
while I need 9 hours before 1 o'clock which is 16 o'clock

Comment: Well, you can just convert it to string and strip the `-` if it is at the index `1` and convert it back to time then...

Answer (score 0):

To subtract (2) different times:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(time_out, time_in);
```

To add (2) different times:

```
SELECT ADDTIME(time1, time2);
```

For more Date and Time Functions, go here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: it works good on full date -as y m d h:m:s - however on only time h- m - s it is inconvenient